# why arithmetic is not possible after assigning value from js variable to php varible?

Tags: javascript, php

i want to get sum of two or more quotients with PHP
I tried to get user input of two digits through js prompt then assign values to php variables
But difficulty in quotient. Is there any best solution??

```
<?php

function quotient($a, $b) {
    return $a / $b;
}
function output($a, $b, $quo) {
    echo "The quotient of ". $a. " and ". $b. " is " . $quo. "<br>";
}

$sum = 0;
$quo = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    echo "<script>
    var a = window.prompt('please enter first digit');
    a = parseInt(a);

    var b = window.prompt('please enter second digit');
    b = parseInt(b);

   </script>";

   $a = "<script>
              document.write(a);
        </script>";
   $b = "<script>
             document.write(b);
        </script>";

   $quo = quotient($a, $b);

   $sum += $quo;
   output($a, $b, $quo);
}

echo "The sum of " . $i . " quotient is " . $sum;
?>
```

Comment: Use only javascript only. It will make your code easier.

Comment: i know, easy with js but i want with php

Comment: You want to take input from prompt only?

Comment: why division can't be done after assigning

Comment: Php variables `$a` and `$b` are in string, they have to be integer/float etc to perform operations.

Comment: yes because in php i dont know how to get input in a loop

Comment: i used parseInt function before assigning to php variable

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check this and tell if it is okay or not

Comment: Thanks that's really i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sumOfQuotient = 0;
    for(var i=0 ; i<2 ;i++){
         var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter first digit"));
         var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter second digit"));
         if(b != 0){
            document.write("First digit:"+a+" Second Digit:"+b+"<br>");
            document.write("Quotient:"+parseInt(a/b)+"<br>"); //if you want quotient to be integer, else remove parseInt()
            sumOfQuotient += parseInt(a/b);
         }
    }
    document.write("Sum of quotient: "+sumOfQuotient);
</script>
```

Using PHP:

Two file which will do the work:

1. home.php - takes the input
2. process.php - perform the operation

I have taken two input for demo. You can take as many as you want

Home.php:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstDigits = new Array();
    var secondDigits = new Array();
    for(var i=0 ; i<2 ;i++){
         firstDigits[i] = parseInt(prompt("Input #"+(i+1)+" Enter first digit"));
         secondDigits[i] = parseInt(prompt("Input #"+(i+1)+" Enter second digit"));     
    }
    $.ajax({
        data:{a:firstDigits,b:secondDigits},
        method: "POST",
        url:"process.php",
        success: function(msg){
            alert("Sum of quotient: "+msg);
        }
    });
</script>
```

process.php:

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $sumOfQuotient = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
        if($b[$i] != 0 ) $sumOfQuotient += $a[$i] / $b[$i];
    }
    echo (int)$sumOfQuotient;
?>
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: yes  because in php i dont know how to get input in a loop

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing like passing a variable from JS to PHP. JS and PHP are running on different machines and direct two-way communication is not possible.

There are various techniques to pass data between JS and PHP, but first you need to realize what part of your code is processed on which computer, and what is scope of each of the variables.

PHP runs on server. JS runs in web browser on client (there is a way to run JS on server, but that is not your case). No variables are shared between them.

Easiest way to pass data from PHP to JS is to generate JS code and then send it to client, where the web browser will interpret it. You can also generate JSON file or create HTML elements (or their attributes). To do so, you need a simple `echo` and `htmlspecialchars()` or [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP:

```
<?php
$a = 123;
// generate JS code in <script> element:
echo "var a = (", json_encode($a), ");\n";
// generate HTML elements:
echo "<span>", htmlspecialchars($a), "</span>\n";
?>
```

To pass data from JS to PHP you need to send HTTP request from client to server. On server a new instance of PHP will be executed and will have the data available.

Easiest way to do so is to submit HTML form. Your data will be passed using `$_POST` and/or `$_GET` superglobal variables. Alternatively you can use [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) in JS to invoke the HTTP request without navigating to another page. There are many [nice libraries](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do that in a few lines of code. Usually it is better to use plain HTML form to transmit data to server, but some use-cases require more interactivity.

Significantly more complex way which allows real-time bidirectional communication requires use of [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). You most likely do not need it.

Comment: I see 2 upvotes for the question and no votes for this good answer .

Comment: Nice explanation.